# Count the number of child categories in hierarchical postgresql structure

Tags: postgresql

I have a table with categories (id, name, parent_id) and that parent_id is an id of an upper category.
I get my category tree via the following query:

```
 WITH RECURSIVE query AS (
    SELECT id, name, parent_id
    FROM category  
        UNION all
    SELECT s2.id, s2.name, s2.parent_id
    FROM category  s2 join query on query.id= s2.parent_id 
)
SELECT * from query order by parent_id;
```

How can I count the child categories in my table?

Comment: Hint: COUNT() function

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe tracking the `depth` of your recursive-ocity will give you the answer. I almost always add a `depth` and `path` into my recursive CTE's because it's a quick add and they offer a wealth of helpful information in the result set:

```
WITH RECURSIVE query AS (
    SELECT id, name, parent_id, 1 as depth, CAST(id || '>' || parent_id as VARCHAR(500)) as path
    FROM category  
        UNION all
    SELECT s2.id, s2.name, s2.parent_id, query.depth + 1, query.path || '>' || s2.parent_id
    FROM category  s2 join query on query.id= s2.parent_id 
)
SELECT * from query order by depth, path;
```

That may not get at exactly what you are needing, but you can `COUNT()` in your final query too:

```
SELECT parent_id, count(*) from query GROUP BY parent_id;
```

Which should give you the count of records from your recursive result set for each parent_id, which theoretically, should be the count of children, right?

Comment: good hint, the recursive query you provided above doesn't really match my expectation. But the count option is more than ok, however, how could I display also id and name, before the summary?

Comment: You can add in name here as well `SELECT parent_id, name, count(*) FROM query GROUP BY parent_id, name`  Glad it solved the problem!